# Visual Studio Team Services - Git Repo credentials

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project in GitHub, I've been a GitHHub user for years, but I now want to use some of the Visual Studio Team Services features so I create a free account and create a project along with a a new Git repo hosted on VS Team Services.  I want to add the new Team Services repository to the list of remotes in my existing repo but I can't authenticate to it from Git Bash using the HTTPS ref and my Team Services credentials.

Is it using some sort of funky auth. mechanism that won't work with standard mysysgit? Do I need to perform some sort of admin on my Team Services account?

Comment: Enable alternate credentials. You should use a simplier, not email address-like username. You can find it under your profile in VSO site.

Comment: Excellent, please write this up as the answer so I can tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your profile please enable alternate authentication credentials and use simpler username than email address.

[image]

Comment: This option is gone as of today.

Answer (score 1):

[Alternate authentication credentials are not recommended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0zxz.png)

It's better to use personal access tokens. Keep in mind though that these expire after a set expiry date and time. In the git client, use any username you like (characters only, e.g. Bob, Chalkie, etc.) and use the token as the password.

[Personal access tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psih3.png)